# How to search through multiple columns in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

This is part of the query where it supposed to search through morning, afternoon and evening columns in posts table.

```
$add_here .= " AND posts.".$col." IN ('" . implode("',' ",$days) . "')";
```

$col is the variable that holds array or single value for column name supplied by user. Namely 'morning','afternoon','evening'. Do you  know how to alter the query above to search in the array($col)?

The below works because I specified column name which is 'afternoon'. I wonder how to replace the text 'afternoon' with array of values!

```
 $add_here .= " AND posts.afternoon  IN ('" . implode("',' ",$days) . "')";
```

Comment: You will need to build up a series of ORed clauses to check for the matches. But the question suggests that you have a column for each time period which suggests a poorly normalised database (and if normalised this kind of query would probably be a lot easier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `array_map` to build a series of conditions grouped with `OR` :

```
$days = ['sun','mon','tue'];
$col = ['afternoon','morning','night'];
$add_here = '';

$add_here .= sprintf(" AND (%s)",
    implode(' OR ', array_map(
            function($colx) use ($days) {
                return sprintf("posts.%s IN ('%s')", $colx, implode("','",$days));
            }, is_array($col) ? $col : array($col))
    )
);
```

> AND (posts.afternoon IN ('sun','mon','tue') OR posts.morning IN
>   ('sun','mon','tue') OR posts.night IN ('sun','mon','tue'))

Comment: I got error: Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in ...., Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in .... What's the output of the above function please?

Comment: $col is expected to be an array. Are you using it with a string, maybe? If it is so, just convert it into array with $col = array($col) before calling that.

Comment: AND (posts.afternoon IN ('Sun',' Sun') OR posts.evening IN ('Sun',' Sun'))

Comment: @Keren Uh? What is the content of `$days`?

Comment: @Keren Ok, careful, I had a bug that puts a space in ' Sun'. Fixed in the answer.

Comment: but your updated answer, doesn't search through all items in the array but only the last one like this: AND (posts.evening IN ('Sun','Sun'))

Comment: @Keren Not quite in my local. Added initalization of arrays and the result I got in my machine. Give it a go.